# Insert new row with current Identity as value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Don't ask me why, but I want to have a column where Identity is stored as varchar. Is it possible to assign this during creation or do I need to Scope Identity and Update?

EDIT: To clarify this is an existing table that I cannot amend in any way. I just want to insert new rows.

Normally I would do this:

```
INSERT INTO [User]
(
    -- id -- this column value is auto-generated,
    useridcr,
    dtcr,
    varcharid
)
VALUES
(
    25,
    '2015-01-30 00:00:00.000'
    ''
)

SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE [User]
SET
    varcharid = @id
WHERE id = @id
```

But is it possible to know the value of new identity before it's created? So I could use the value in the insert statement. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO [User]
(
    -- id -- this column value is auto-generated,
    useridcr,
    dtcr,
    varcharid
)
VALUES
(
    25,
    '2015-01-30 00:00:00.000'
    [generatedID]
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a **trigger** to the table? That could set your `varchar` column to the value of the newly inserted identity value

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`computed column`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**:

```
CREATE TABLE [User]
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    useridcr INT,
    dtcr INT ,
    varcharid AS CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10))
);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383634)**</kbd>

Then you don't need to catching last generating value and updating data.

Alternatively you can use `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_user
AS
SELECT *,
   [varcharid] = CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM [User]
```

**EDIT:**

You can use trigger for that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_User
ON [User]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE u
  SET varcharid = CAST(i.id AS VARCHAR(100))
  FROM [User] u
  JOIN inserted i
    ON u.id = i.id;
END
GO
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6676a)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited my original post. That table already exists and I cannot amend it.

Comment: @Zikato Can you use second solution with `VIEW`?

Comment: I admit I'm new to VIEW, but how could I fit it inside insert statement?

Comment: @Zikato INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE table, read from view. Alternatively you could use trigger, see updated]